# "IOError: closed stream" error when authenticating on xmpp4r_facebook

Tags: facebook, xmpp, xmpp4r

This is quite strange since it used to work, and now it doesn't. If it was 'Not Authorized' error, it would have been easy, but with "IOError: closed stream", I am stumped.

I thought it may have been due to expired token, but access token gets updated whenever user signs in with Facebook.

Since encountering errors, I tried step-by-step and found out it happens when auth_sasl method is called.

```
1.9.3p194 :073 > c = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new("-[FB_ID]@chat.facebook.com"))
[output omitted]
1.9.3p194 :074 > c.connect
[output omitted]
1.9.3p194 :079 > c.is_connected?
=> true 
1.9.3p194 :080 > c.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(c, [FB_KEY], [TOKEN], [FB_SECRET]), nil)
IOError: closed stream
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:318:in `syswrite'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:318:in `do_write'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:383:in `<<'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/xmpp4r-0.5/lib/xmpp4r/stream.rb:346:in `block in send_data'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/xmpp4r-0.5/lib/xmpp4r/stream.rb:344:in `send_data'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/xmpp4r-0.5/lib/xmpp4r/stream.rb:378:in `send'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/xmpp4r_facebook-0.1.1/lib/xmpp4r_facebook.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from (irb):80:in `new'
    from (irb):80
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/yangtheman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3p194 :081 > c.is_connected?
=> false
```

Can anyone please shed some light on why this could be happening? Anyone else having the same or similar problem?

**EDIT:** I turned on the debug, and the following is the "error" message I received. Again, it seems like many people have the same problem, but there isn't any solution or explanation to the problem I could find. Big :(.

```
<subject>Sorry, your account isn&apos;t available</subject><body>Your account is temporarily unavailable. Regain access by logging into your account from a web browser.</body></message>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I'm consistently encounter this 1 year later. I think the only way for it to get solved is to submit the issue to facebook tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with the same issue on multiple OS's & clients - *definitely* server-side issue, but not getting any response from FB on the issue.
Issue started presenting after I enabled 2FA in FB - not sure if it's the root-cause. Chat is important, but the little "security" provided by FB is more so.

Comment: This post might be better as a comment :)